# Eslint disable no console not working

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to log to console something by disabling the no console rule in eslint like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(props.hasSubmittedForm);
```

But, I get an error:

> Module build failed
>
> unexpected token

For the dot the console.log.
Why can't I log to the console like that?

Comment: wrap your console.log with `/* eslint-disable no-console */`

Answer (score 24):

Interestingly for me when I switch from `eslint-disable-next-line` to `eslint-disable` I have to also change the comment from `//` to `/* */`.

This didn't work:

```
// eslint-disable no-console
```

✅ This worked:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
```

Answer (score 10):

You can wrap your code with `/* eslint-disable no-console */` in order to disable eslint just for that part:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
console.log(props.hasSubmittedForm);
/* eslint-enable no-console */
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't stage the `eslint-disable...` change? My code failed running the `pre-commit` hook, after staging the `eslint-disable...` change, it passed the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping (which is using two lines), or disable the whole file, you can simply use above the concerned line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log("I am ignored");
```